# Where is docker mysql file persisted on local system

Tags: mysql, docker

I've created a simple React/spring-boot/mysql app which I've now ported into docker, including data persisting between deletions of the mysql container. According to docker-compose.yml, the local storage should be at /var/lib/mysql, but I don't see it there.

This makes me nervous - where is the data being stored? I want to make sure it's on the local filesystem and not in some container which I might easily delete.

Here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:

  # Backend Service

  app-server:
    image: licensing-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod"
      - "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxx"
      - "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxx"

  # Frontend Service
  app-client:
    image: license_front_end
    ports:
      - "3000:80" 
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app-server
    networks:
      - backend 

  # Database Service (Mysql)

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
        MYSQL_DATABASE: license_db
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend

# Volumes
volumes:
  db-data:

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  backend:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in a Docker named volume.  You can't (*) directly access it, but it will get persisted across runs.  Repeating `docker-compose up` will reuse an existing volume, even if the database container is deleted and recreated; [by default](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) `docker-compose down` will not delete the volume (you explicitly need a `--volumes` option).

If you want to be able to directly see the files (and have an easier time backing them up) you can use a bind-mounted host directory instead.  Depending on your host OS, these could have rather different performance and permission characteristics.  (On MacOS especially, bind mounts are very slow, so if you're in a development setup and recreating the database is possible, you might prefer a named volume if the database content is totally opaque anyways.)

```yaml
services:
  mysqldb:
    volumes:
      # Relative or absolute path, but not a bare name
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

(*) If you go poking around in `/var/lib/docker` on a native-Linux host you can find the named-volume contents, but this is an implementation detail, and I don't think Docker actually makes any stability guarantees about the format of what's stored in that directory; using a bind mount is much better practice than poking around in Docker's internal storage.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Why does bind-mounting make backups easier - maybe it's in the same directory you're running from? Also, would you use separate names for test and prod? E.g. ./db-data:var/lib/mysql_prod and ./db-data:var/lib/mysql_test?

Comment: I'd use separate hosts for test and production.  The container-side path `/var/lib/mysql` is fixed but you can change the host path if you do have different setups; you can also run multiple parallel copies of the same Docker Compose setup.

Comment: As far as other content in `/var/lib/docker` goes, you should be able to pull or rebuild images again, and containers are design to be disposable, and also the image/container data format _has_ changed over time.  Docker Desktop for Mac has a specific option to include the opaque Docker VM from the OS (Time Machine) backups.  But, if you exclude all Docker content, that includes named volumes too.